# What is the oscillation period of a pendulum near a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

Does a pendulum near the event horizon of a solar-mass black hole oscillate much slower or much faster than an identical pendulum on Earth when taking into account the GR gravitational time dilation and the increase in gravitational acceleration near the event horizon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oscillation of a pendulum near a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686269/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no unique answer, because there is no unique time reference in the universe. As always, you need to specify "as measured by X" or "relative to X". Relative to an observer standing next to the pendulum (in both cases) the BH pendulum oscillates much faster than the Earth pendulum. If both are measured by an observer standing on Earth, the exact outcome will depend on just how close to the event horizon the other pendulum is -- time dilation will increase without bound as you approach the event horizon, so you can always pick some location where (as seen from Earth) the BH pendulum is slower than the Earth pendulum.

Also note that the tidal forces near a solar mass black hole are enormous, so any real world pendulum would probably be torn apart.

Comment: Say the observer is on the surface of the Earth and the pendulum is at two event horizon radii near the BH. What is the resulting effect?

Comment: You could in principle calculate it; for example, the time dilation due to gravity may be found at https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/gravitational-time-dilation. The "proper acceleration" needed to hover at $2r_s$ may be calculated from the formula given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration, and the pendulum's period would follow from that (the proper acceleration corresponds to the "gravity" felt by the pendulum). But I"m curious: what are you trying to learn?

Comment: I am interested about the combined competing effects of classical g(r) and GR time dilation  in extreme cases upon a stationary pendulum (excluding SR effects) near a BH, as seen by an observer on Earth. I have learned that at any altitude above Earth g(r) affects the period of a pendulum a lot more than the weaker GR redshift. For Earth I found the result that the the pendulum oscillates slower due to less gravity. So I conjectured that there should be a "transition point" if gravity gets much  stronger. To see, I will try to do the calculations.